# How to get the account id with cdk

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I wrote a simple typescript with AWS CDK and try to get the account id

```
import cdk = require("@aws-cdk/core");

const app = new cdk.Stack();

console.log(app.account);
```

But get below output

```
$ tsc index.ts 
$ node index.js 
${Token[AWS::AccountId.0]}
```

So what's the meaning of `Token` here? How to get the real account id?

#### Updates

```
$ cdk init app --language=typescript

# replace lib/<name>-stack.ts with @Rob Raisch 's code

$ cdk synth
${Token[AWS::AccountId.0]}
Outputs:
  MyStackAccount:
    Description: Account of this stack
    Value:
      Ref: AWS::AccountId
Resources:
  CDKMetadata:
    Type: AWS::CDK::Metadata
    Properties:
      Modules: aws-cdk=1.2.0,@aws-cdk/core=1.8.0,@aws-cdk/cx-api=1.8.0,jsii-runtime=node.js/v10.15.3

$ cdk deploy
${Token[AWS::AccountId.0]}
MyStack: deploying...
MyStack: creating CloudFormation changeset...
 0/2 | 11:58:59 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CDK::Metadata | CDKMetadata Resource creation Initiated
 1/2 | 11:58:59 AM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CDK::Metadata | CDKMetadata 
 2/2 | 11:59:00 AM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | MyStack 

 ✅  MyStack

Outputs:
MyStack.MyStackAccount = 123456789012
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue until I realized that, until you run `cdk deploy`, there are no such values, only placeholders (like `${Token[AWS::AccountId.0]}`) that will be filled in during deployment.

Think of it this way, your CDK stack is a plan to create a number of resources, but until you run `cdk deploy`, those resources do not exist and so, cannot be queried for their values.

One way to get the value you need would be to add this to your stack constructor:

```
// Publish the custom resource output
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "MyStackAccount", {
  description: "Account of this stack",
  value: this.account
});
```

As in:

```
class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, "MyStack", props);

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "MyStackAccount", {
      description: "Account of this stack",
      value: this.account
    });
  }
}
```

which, when you run `cdk deploy`, will output:

```
MyStack.StackAccount = 987XXXXXX456
```

Comment: To add to this, if you're inside of a Construct, you can get the account ID with `this.env.account` instead of `this.account`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the environment variable `CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT`:

```
console.log(process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT)
```

Quoting [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html):

> ...your stack can use two environment variables provided by the AWS CDK CLI: CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT and CDK_DEFAULT_REGION. These variables are set based on the AWS profile specified using the --profile option, or the default AWS profile if you don't specify one.

Note: I'm using version `2.84.0` of `aws-cdk`

Answer (score 1):

The question is "How to get the account id" but you don't mention why.

If you want to get your Account number for IAM purposes, such as only allowing your account to use your API Gateway (for example), then you can also use the Principal type `AccountRootPrincipal` which always points to the "current" account.

```
    const policy = new PolicyStatement({
      effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      actions: ['execute-api:Invoke'],
      resources: ['arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*/*'],
      principals: [new AccountRootPrincipal()], // <-- Your account only
    });
```

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work for my use case with generating an iam.User `A PolicyStatement used in an identity-based policy cannot specify any IAM principals.`